# Socket.io client with non-socket.io server

Tags: sockets, websocket, socket.io

I trying to connect to the non-socket.io websocket server using socket.io client. But I can't to do it. 
I'm trying to connect to socket server like this:

```
var socket = io.connect('wss://url-to-socket-api/');
```

And getting the error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://url-to-socket-api/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1452852826678-0. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://192.168.33.10' is therefore not allowed access.
```

But when I connect to the server with web socket API like this:

```
var socket = new WebSocket('wss://url-to-socket-api');
```

It's works.

Is it possible to use socket.io client with non-socket.io server?

Comment: Despite the URLs commonly used with `socket.io`, it's not a websocket protocol but custom implementation. See https://socket.io/docs/v4/#what-socketio-is-not for details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can't use Socket.io client with non-socket.io server. In this case use WebSocket. There is few links:

http://www.developerfusion.com/article/143158/an-introduction-to-websockets/

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/start-using-html5-websockets-today--net-13270